# time.sleep is hanging

Tags: python, timer, gevent, python-requests

This is some strange regression that I can only reproduce on the more powerful production machine we have.

```
def test_foo(self):
    res = self._run_job( ....)
    self.assertTrue("Hello Input!" in res.json()["stdout"], res.text)
    .........

def _run_job(self, cbid, auth, d):    
    .........
    while True:
        res = requests.get(URL+"/status/"+status_id, auth=auth)   <--- hangs here
        if res.json()["status"] != "Running":
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(2)
    ..........
```

I have to break the process and this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_full.py", line 231, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/main.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/main.py", line 232, in runTests
    self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/runner.py", line 162, in run
    test(result)
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/suite.py", line 64, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/suite.py", line 84, in run
    self._wrapped_run(result)
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/suite.py", line 114, in _wrapped_run
    test._wrapped_run(result, debug)
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/suite.py", line 116, in _wrapped_run
    test(result)
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/case.py", line 398, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/case.py", line 340, in run
    testMethod()
  File "test_full.py", line 59, in test_session
    "cmd": "python helloworld.py"
  File "test_full.py", line 129, in _run_job
    time.sleep(2)
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 79, in sleep
    switch_result = get_hub().switch()
  File "/opt/graphyte/vens/gcs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 164, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception KeyError: KeyError(155453036,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Why is `gevent` involved? This is a functional test. It only makes HTTP requests through `requests` library so maybe the `switch` refers to `requests`.

But being a simple loop, how could this fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you monkey patching in gevent?

It could be switching on the network request and never getting back for some reason. I'd say stop monkey patching for now, and put in gevent where you need it.

It could be that now that requests is asynchronous, it's returning immediately, then sleeping (again asynchronously) and the requesting, and rinse / repeat...

Comment: That was indeed part of the problem. Fixed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> Why is `gevent` involved?

The `gevent` library monkey-patches some standard modules to make them cooperative. Replacing `time.sleep` by `gevent.sleep` is one of the changes.

http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html#gevent.monkey.patch_time

Comment: I did. I did use gevent.sleep but it will hang at `requests`.